How to use importlib with zipapp?
I have a module that works
# main.py
from importlib import resources

def main() -> None:
    with resources.path("data", "config.json") as path:
        with open(path, 'r') as f_config:
            text = f_config.read()
        print(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

But when I create a zipapp file and run that I get the error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data'

This is my project structure
.
└── src
    ├── data
    │   ├── config.json
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── main.py


and this is my zipapp file

What do I need to do?
